# Вопрос про парсер CsQuery

Tags: c#

Всех приветствую, вопрос такой, изучаю этот парсер, вот страница, которую я хочу разобрать. Вот мой код.
Вопрос, на странице с резюме заголовок резюме является ссылкой при нажатии на которую резюме раскрывается, как парсить такие вещи, вроде парсер не может кликнуть на ссылку. чтобы отработал скрипт и открыл.

```
namespace Parse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string urri = @"https://www.rabota66.ru/resume/rbranch3";
            string txt= Connect(urri);

            CQ cq = CQ.Create(txt);
            var q = cq["div.title- > a.title- "].Text();
            Console.WriteLine(q);

            var ps = cq["div>p"];
            foreach (var p in ps)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.FirstChild);
            }    

            Console.ReadKey();    
        }

        public static string Connect(string uri)
        {    
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);

            var responce = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            string html = null;
            using (responce)
            {    
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responce, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                return html;
            }    
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, ваш вопрос содержит два вопроса. Во-вторых, вопрос номер 1- решается путем построения класса с двумя свойствами, а второй - путем парсинга другой страницы.

Comment: @Monomax Про первый вопрос понятно, буду делать класс для хранения всего что парситься. А вот про второй вопрос не понял.

Comment: Когда вы парсите, у вас почти наверняка парсится ссылка на страницу с подробностями, вот эту страницу надо парсить отдельно, а результаты добавлять в созданный вами класс.

Comment: @Monomax да информация есть, только не знаю как мне к ней прицепиться, информация в коде есть

Comment: Поэтому на вопрос вам не ответят, а вот если создадите два вопроса, как я понимаю вам можно создавать один, но новый. либо переформулировать данный, но под конкретные нужды, то вам почти наверняка ответят.

Comment: @Monomax переформулировал вопрос